# Kendo UI Chart Structure got messed on refresh

Tags: svg, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-chart, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using Angular 2 and Kendo UI for showing Bar graph. Functionality is like once the form is submitted so as per data and some calculation bar graph will be generated and works like a charm!

The Results is like below:

[image: Kendo UI Chart Good Output]

Once user will refresh the page, then I am getting Kendo Chart result like below:

[image: Kendo UI Chart Bad Output]

After reloading page, Attributes(`Stroke, fill`) of SVG element(`g, path`) having transparent value (`rgba(255,255,255,0)`).

Kendo Chart Code:

```
             <kendo-chart >
                <kendo-chart-title text="{{ returnObject.designation }} Score card - {{ chartObject.getTotalSum }}% Match" color ="#337ab7" ></kendo-chart-title>
                    <kendo-chart-value-axis>
                        <kendo-chart-value-axis-item [min]="0" [max]="10" >
                        </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
                        <kendo-chart-series-defaults type="bar">
                            <kendo-chart-series-defaults-labels format="c">
                            </kendo-chart-series-defaults-labels>
                        </kendo-chart-series-defaults>
                    </kendo-chart-value-axis>
                    <kendo-chart-category-axis>
                        <kendo-chart-category-axis-item  [categories]="chartObject.skills">
                        </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
                    </kendo-chart-category-axis>
                    <kendo-chart-series>
                        <kendo-chart-series-item  type="bar" color="#337ab7" [data]="chartObject.rates">
                        </kendo-chart-series-item>
                    </kendo-chart-series>
                </kendo-chart>
```

Note : Result of All JSON data and the Kendo UI CSS is coming perfect, but the UI is messy, this all issues are related to SVG elements under Kendo UI chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the bug for Kendo UI!!

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/npm/node_modules/@telerik/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css" />`

This is the stylesheet for kendo UI and I kept it at component level. so somehow it was creating as issue for loading css and attributes as well.

I kept this stylesheet link at application level. I mean in `index.html`. and Issue is solved! Chart is working like a charm!